# RPi Pico + Arduino IDE: Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU

Tags: display, arduino, c++, pi-pico

I've bought a [SSD1306](https://www.amazon.com/SSD1306/s?k=SSD1306)-compatible display for my Raspberry Pi Pico. However, it uses some kind of non-standard encoding and the typical Adafruit libraries don't work. The seller says I should use the [U8G2](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2) library & Arduino IDE to communicate with it.

I've downloaded Arduino IDE and tried to upload [the *“Blink“* example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Blink) to the RPi. It worked just fine, I've managed to make the internal LED blink. However, trying to run the U8G2 *“Hello world”* example, I got the following errors:

```
In included file: "Compiler generates FPU instructions for
a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)
clang(pp_hash_error)

Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

[image]

However, the Pico does have a FPU, right? Are there some settings I need to change to get the Arduino IDE working with my RPi?

Comment: As a guess it is down to the (unknown) development environment being used.

Comment: *"the Pico does have a FPU, right"* -> No, and neither do Arduinos.

Comment: The processors in the pico and the arduino are dirt cheap. An fpu would increase the cost exponentially and it's not necessary for their common use.